# Understanding Minimum Output Voltage of Cascode Current Mirror

Tags: transistors, mosfet, analog, bias, nmos

[image]

I guess that I have some serious trouble understanding how to get the saturation equation for the cascode current mirror right which is known from all the textbooks as

$$
V_{out} = 2 V_{DS, sat} + V_{th}
$$

It's quite intuitive to get to the point that the gate voltage at Q4 needs to be

$$
V_{G, Q4} = 2 V_{DS, sat} + 2 V_{th}
$$

Now when looking at how a MOSFET is saturated we use \$ V_{DS} \geq V_{GS} - V_{th} \$. So applying this to Q4, why do we just simply do

$$
V_{D, Q4} = V_{out} = V_{G, Q4} - V_{th} = 2 V_{DS, sat} +V_{th}
$$

? That doesn't work for me because we look at \$ V_{G, Q4} \$ with respect to ground, so for me it makes sense to write

$$
V_{out} = V_{G, Q4} - V_{S, Q4} - V_{th} = V_{G, Q4} - V_{D, Q2} - V_{th}
$$

But we don't know \$V_{D, Q2}\$. When assuming \$V_{D, Q2} = V_{D, Q1}\$ we get

$$
V_{out} = 2 V_{DS, sat} + 2 V_{th} - V_{DS, sat} - V_{th} - V_{th} = V_{DS, sat}
$$

which obviously is nonsense... So where did I get stuck or where did I go seriously wrong?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: We got a talking amplifier over here. I would expect your entire question to be in caps lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*so for me it makes sense to write*

$$
V_{out} = V_{G, Q4} - V_{S, Q4} - V_{th} = V_{G, Q4} - V_{D, Q2} - V_{th}
$$

But that does not make sense as 
$$
V_{G, Q4} - V_{S, Q4} = V_{GS, Q4}
$$

So you're calculating Vds of Q4 and **not** Vout.

You should add the Vds of Q2 into the equation.

Comment: Thank you a lot for clarification, now this is truly awkward that I didn't notice it myself.

Comment: I find your formula is very confusing. First, Vout is not VG(Q4) - VS(Q4) - Vth. It should be Vout(min) = VG(Q4) - Vth.  Second, VG(Q4) - VS(Q4) = VGS(Q4) MAKES NO SENSE to you? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my stepwise thought process to find the Minimum Output Voltage of Cascode Current Mirror.

[image]